# upload image is stuck when using multer.js (upload.any)

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, multer

I am experiencing vary strange behavior. I created a small test which simplify the problem.
I have a simple POST rest API which supposed to parse an image which I am getting as multipart/form-data content type.

This is the server important  code parts:

```
var    upload = multer({
            storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
            limits: {
                files: 1,
                fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5// 5 MB
            }
        }).any();


app.post('/v(\\d+)/image', function (req, res) {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('upload image to server failed-' + (err.code || err), `uploadImage`);
                res.status(500).json({err: (err.code || err)});
                return;
            }

console.log('upload image to server succeed');
    });
```

**This is the test which post the request every x second:**

```
var request = require('request');
var fs= require('fs');


    var  formData = {
        "image_context_type": 1,
        attachments: [
            fs.createReadStream(file_dir)
        ]
    };


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    setTimeout(function(){
    formData.image_uid = uuid.v4();

    request.post({
        url: 'http://<server ip>:8888/v1/image', formData: formData
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        console.log('err-' + err);
        console.log('res-' + res.statusCode);

    });
    }, 1000*i);
}
```

The behavior:
In case of 1 second timeout (1000 milliseconds) only the first image which i send is getting to the server callback upload part (the rest are stuck).

In case of 0 second timeout (0 milliseconds) all the image which I send are getting to the server callback upload part (the rest are stuck).

this occurs only on EC2 Ubuntu  14.04 machine, even when execute the test from the same EC2 machine (localhost). I can't reproduce it on my development local VM.

Comment: where is destination path ?

Comment: I am saving the file in memory (later on I am uploading it to S3).

Comment: use fiddler/wireshark to see if requests are sent at all or stuck at client side

Comment: the problem was that we re use the fs.createReadStream.